# Parse and count structured text to build statistics

Tags: ruby, parsing

I have a specific problem that I just can't find a solution for. 
I get data in the following format from a text file

```
    date1 reason1
    date1 reason1
    date1 reason2
    date1 reason3
    date2 reason4
    date2 reason1
    date2 reason2
    date2 reason2
    date2 reason1
    date2 reason3
    date3 reason4
    date3 reason4
    date3 reason1
```

I want to build statistics on the data e.g. I want to count all different "reasons" from each date like this

```
    date1 reason1 -> 2        
    date1 reason2 -> 1
    date1 reason3 -> 1
    date2 reason1 -> 2
    date2 reason4 -> 1
    date2 reason2 -> 2
    date1 reason3 -> 1
```

...and so on. How would I parse the data and build the required result? I guess hashes would be used but I failed to imagine a way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very straight forward approach:

```
h = Hash.new(0)
File.foreach("foo.txt") do |line|
  h[line.chomp] += 1  
end  
h
#=> {"date1 reason1"=>2,
 "date1 reason2"=>1,
 "date1 reason3"=>1,
 "date2 reason4"=>1,
 "date2 reason1"=>2,
 "date2 reason2"=>2,
 "date2 reason3"=>1,
 "date3 reason4"=>2,
 "date3 reason1"=>1}
```

Comment: Embarassing how easy it can be - this solved my problem like a charm. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "date1 reason1
date1 reason1
date1 reason2
date1 reason3
date2 reason4
date2 reason1
date2 reason2
date2 reason2
date2 reason1
date2 reason3
date3 reason4
date3 reason4
date3 reason1"

line_counts = Hash.new(0)

str.lines.each do |line|
  line_counts[line.chomp] += 1
end

line_counts.each do |line, count|
  puts "#{line} -> #{count}"
end
```

output:

```
date1 reason1 -> 2
date1 reason2 -> 1
date1 reason3 -> 1
date2 reason1 -> 2
date2 reason2 -> 2
date2 reason3 -> 1
date2 reason4 -> 1
date3 reason1 -> 1
date3 reason4 -> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = File.foreach("foo.txt").each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |line,h|
  h[line.chomp] += 1  
end  
#=> {"date1 reason1"=>2,
 "date1 reason2"=>1,
 "date1 reason3"=>1,
 "date2 reason4"=>1,
 "date2 reason1"=>2,
 "date2 reason2"=>2,
 "date2 reason3"=>1,
 "date3 reason4"=>2,
 "date3 reason1"=>1}
```